# How can I record insane action in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording

I used to make videos which had a lot of system-intensive gameplay, for example, 10,000 [TNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT) exploding at the same time.

I used to have a modification that slowed the game down and recorded it frame by frame. I haven't used it since 1.2.5 and so unfortunately can't remember what it was called.

[Video Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4sDgp3Pd-g)

I have a project which I want to result in a large explosion, and I will be using about 50,000 TNT. I have a better computer than I had then, but with shaders I would be hard pressed to find anyone that could pull it off. How could I record something like this?

I have attempted it without any special settings or modifications, and my Minecraft installation just crashes.

My current system specification is:

- [Nvidia GTX 660 Ti](http://www.nvidia.in/object/geforce-gtx-660ti-in.html)
- 16 GB Corsair RAM
- Quad-core 3.8 GHz processor.
- 250 GB [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) and three 2 TB hard disk drives

Comment: That's not intensive, that's _insane_ :)

Comment: are you sure the limit on this is the recording, rather than just minecraft not being able to handle it? the overhead of recording gameplay should be fairly constant.

Comment: @TZHX minecraft doesn't handle explosions well, even a modest 100 tnt in one go will bring the game to its knees without any recording strain

Comment: I can currently set off 1000 while recording with shaders and pick it up well, the video that i put up as an example was me with 5000 tnt a couple years ago. with a much worse computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mod you're talking about is the [**Minema mod**](http://www.5minecraft.net/minema-mod/) <strike>although, as far as I can tell, it's only compatible up to Minecraft 1.6.</strike>

It works at least up to 1.7.2 with [this version](http://nesteria.pl/7err0r/Minema-2.0.jar).

A good rundown of Minema, as well as a few others, is given in this Yogscast video:

Comment: I think this was the mod that i originally used thanks for that but would still be interesting if there are any other solutions. especially for 1.7.2 or 1.7.9 as that has better shaders

Comment: @Flaunting I had a quick search but couldn't find anything. Some people seem to have possibly got it working on 1.7.5 though, but I couldn't see any concrete proof.

Comment: could you share the link to that i would love to test it

Comment: @Flaunting [Read around here. Some people profess to have it working on 1.7.x but I'm not sure](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1280148-minema-2-0-beta3-the-smooth-movie-recorder?page=75)

Comment: Thanks alot fredley I am going to check this out this evening because i would love to get this to work with FTB Unstable with shaders. for anyone interested this is the link to the 1.7.2 version to save scrolling through the forum [Minema 1.7.2](http://nesteria.pl/7err0r/Minema-2.0.jar)

Comment: I can now confirm that it works on 1.7.2 with all features. could you update your answer so that this is clear with both links